# CSS position:fixed never works at all in my site but works in other site

Tags: html, css, position, fixed

When I used **CSS** `position:fixed`, it never works at all in one of my site but works in other site.

I couldn't find out any reason. It works perfect in all of my developing sites in all browser.

However, `position:fixed` never works in one site only wherever I put it except for **Firefox**.

**Example:**

```
<div style="position:fixed">
    This div is fixed
</div>
```

This  never fixed its position.

Now the  is fixed but it doesn't stick to the window when scrolled as it does in **Firefox**.

Comment: Isnt it in any relative container? Or iframe?

Comment: use `position: fixed; left: 0;  top: 0; `try also `z-index `

Comment: Thanks @SathishS .NOw the div is fixed but it doesn't stick to the window when scroll as it does in firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I found the solution & working on it.

It was because I call some other css files. when i remove one of the css it works perfect.

I don't know why but it works..

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="position: fixed; width:100px; height: 100px;"></div>
```

Don't put the div into relative container.

Comment: thanks , Now the div is fixed but it doesn't stick to the window when scroll as it does in firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `left/right` and `top/left` position.

```
<div style="position: fixed; left: 0; top: 10px;">
```

Comment: thanks , Now the div is fixed but it doesn't stick to the window when scroll as it does in firefox.

Comment: @SurajLois: Not sure if I understand what you want. Any screenshot what is should do and what it's doing right now?

Comment: thanks.. in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6nb5ubak/1/  the div with red border stick to the window.. If i put the same code in my project it works in firefox but in chrome the div with red border scroll with the window (not stick).

Answer (score 0):

It might be coused of parent element overriding your statement. Try adding

```
<div style='position: fixed !important;'>
```